# Google map only loading half of itself

Tags: jquery, google-maps

[image]

Look at the image above and try the url at -> http://domainsoutlook.com/s/site/stackoverflow.com.html and go to server information tab.

The absurd point I notices is that if I load http://domainsoutlook.com/s/site/stackoverflow.com.html#server_information

then the map loads fine

Comment: i am also facing same problem and here is my post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858716/map-is-showing-only-half-of-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `checkResize()` API function after you changing the tab.

First of all move declaration of `map` variable upper, for example:

```
var map;
$(document).ready(function() {
//... your code
```

And then after tab is clicked call `map.checkResize()` function.

Comment: map.checkResize() does not work. However, i have reloaded the map again evey time that tab is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Keep this after displaying the map.

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I made an application in Oracle Apex 3.2 and using JavaScript, a Google Map with a marker is displayed, together with a streetview panel of the location where the marker is. In Internet Explorer the problem with half the map occurred but in Firefox everything went fine. Adding the `map.checkResize()` solved the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my AngularJS app and I solved it by enclosing the map initialization code in $timeout

```
$timeout(function(){
    //Your map initialization code
    scope.initialize();
});
```